# Finding the locus of $z=at+\frac bt$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I have to find the locus of$$
z=at+\frac{b}{t},
$$
where $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ are constants. I took $a=a_1+ia_2$ and $b=b_1+ib_2$, but could not get the solution.

Comment: Hint: What geometric shape does this make? A locus is a set of points (e.g. circle, parabola, line), whose position is satisfied or is determined by one or more specified conditions. Take real and imaginary parts and see what happens...

Answer (score 1):

In a real setting, the curve given by parametric equations

$$\tag{1}x=t, \ \ \ y=\dfrac{1}{t},$$

i.e., with cartesian equation $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$, is a (equilateral) hyperbola.

Of course, (1) can be written

$$\tag{2}x+iy=t\color{red}{1}+\dfrac{1}{t}\color{red}{i}$$

Thus $z=t\color{red}{a}+\dfrac{1}{t}\color{red}{b}$ (see the analogy with (2)) is a hyperbola with respect to oblique axes defined by $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OB}$ ($A,B$ are points associated with complex numbers $a,b$). Thus it is also a hyperbola with respect to standard axes.

Comment: Never seen a more elegant solution!